# How to create an own shape for a QGraphicItem in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qpainterpath

I am new to PyQt5 and I am programming a small Logo-Editor for generating simple Logos. I use PyQt5 Version: 5.15.7 in Python 3.10 all together in PyCharm PyCharm 2022.1.3 (Community Edition) on Windows 11.

I am using the QGraphicsScene to draw all my lines and then I can customize length, color, zValue, etc of the created logo. I use MouseEvents to click on one QGraphicsItem and so I am able to change the color and zValue. That's just for the introduction.

The Problem I have is on creating a diagonal line.
Then the resulting default boundingRect() of the QGraphicsItem is much too big, and this makes problems when I have several lines on my Scene, which I would like to select with the mouse. Then the clicking on one Item results in the selection of a nearby diagonal line item.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[Diagonal line with selection box (black), the red line shows the boundingRect or shape I would like to use)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9e6B.png)

I made a small QtApp to demonstrate my problem:

```python
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent,
    QGraphicsItem,
    QTextEdit,
    )
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPolygonF, QPen, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF, QLineF
import sys


# Own QGraphicsScene Subclass with some drawings and points as example
class MyScene( QGraphicsScene ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__( -300, -300, 600, 600 )
        
        # Set QPen for drawings
        self.my_pen = QPen( Qt.darkBlue )
        self.my_pen.setWidthF( 15 )
        self.my_pen.setCapStyle( Qt.RoundCap )
        
        # Set Start- & End-Points for my line
        self.start = QPointF( 0, 0 )
        self.end = QPointF( 200, 200 )
        
        # Draw a line (boundingRect is created automatically)
        self.lin = self.addLine( QLineF( self.start, self.end ), self.my_pen )
        self.lin.setFlags( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable )
        
        # Change Pen-Setttings for new Item
        self.my_pen.setWidthF( 2 )
        self.my_pen.setColor( Qt.darkRed )
        self.my_pen.setStyle( Qt.DotLine )
        
        # Draw polygon, which I would like to apply on my line as a bounding rect
        self.poly = self.addPolygon(
                QPolygonF(
                        [
                                QPointF( 20, -30 ),
                                QPointF( -30, 20 ),
                                QPointF( 180, 230 ),
                                QPointF( 230, 180 ),
                                ] ),
                self.my_pen
                )
    
    # Reimplementing the mousePressEvent for catching some information
    def mousePressEvent( self, sceneEvent: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent ):
        # Get position and item at the position of the event
        
        #### EDIT after Comments from musicamente
        #### FIRST pass the event to the original implementation of the mousePressEvent
        super().mousePressEvent( sceneEvent )
        #### and THEN get the position of the item at the event-scenePosition
        pp = sceneEvent.scenePos()
        
        current_item = self.itemAt( pp, QTransform() )
        # So if there is an item at the clicked position, then write some information
        if current_item is not None:
            text = f"scenePos() = {pp} \n"\
                   f"screenPos() = {sceneEvent.screenPos()}\n"\
                   f"current_item.boundingRect() = "\
                   f"{current_item.boundingRect()}\n"\
                   f"current_item.shape() = {current_item.shape()}\n"\
                   f"current_item.shape().boundingRect() = "\
                   f"{current_item.shape().boundingRect()}\n"\
                   f"current_item.shape().controlPointRect() = "\
                   f"{current_item.shape().controlPointRect()}\n"\
                   f""
            my_gui.my_textedit.setText( text )
            current_item.mousePressEvent( sceneEvent )


# The Class/Widget for placing the view and a QTextEdit
class MyGui( QWidget ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry( 50, 50, 800, 800 )
        self.my_scene = MyScene()
        self.my_view = QGraphicsView( self )
        self.my_view.setScene( self.my_scene )
        
        # QTextEdit for displaying some stuff for debuggin
        self.my_textedit = QTextEdit( self )
        self.my_textedit.setGeometry( 0, 610, 600, 150 )


# Starting the App
my_app = QApplication( sys.argv )
my_gui = MyGui()
my_gui.show()

sys.exit( my_app.exec() )
```

In the textEdit I see roughly, what I have to do:

```
current_item.shape() = <PyQt5.QtGui.QPainterPath object at 0x00000213C8DD9A10>
current_item.shape().boundingRect() = PyQt5.QtCore.QRectF(-30.707106781186553, -30.999999999983665, 261.70710678117024, 261.70710678117024)
current_item.shape().controlPointRect() = PyQt5.QtCore.QRectF(-30.707106781186553, -31.09763107291604, 261.8047378541026, 261.8047378541026)
```

I found some questions here addressing the same problem, but they are in C++

- [How to minimize Bounding Rect in qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407209/how-to-minimize-bounding-rect-in-qt)
- [Customizing shape of bounding rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271623/customizing-shape-of-bounding-rect)
- And also one in Python
  [Drawing shapes using PYQT5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666792/drawing-shapes-using-pyqt5)  but honestly I don't know how to transfer this to my "smaller" problem I have.

I understand that I have to reimplement the shape() of my line...
BUT I don't have a clue how to do this in my example...

Can somebody give me a hint, how to solve this?

I haven't found some information on the internet regarding problems like this. If you know any Websites with tutorials on these topics, I would be very pleased to know them. Or a book dealing with Graphics in PyQt5 would be also great.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: First of all, the bounding rect of an item is always orthogonal to its coordinate system. An oblique line will always have a bounding rectangle that includes its extremities as the opposite corners of the rectangle. Then, you should let the scene handle mouse events in order to properly use the default behavior, so don't call the item's `mouseEvent` but the base function: `super().mousePressEvent(sceneEvent)`. This is because `itemAt()` only returns the *topmost* item at those coordinates, so even if the shape is correct (and it is) you're not allowing the scene to compute the *actual* item.

Comment: Many Thanks @musicamente for  fast reply :-)
1) So the boundingRect of an item is also used to display the - let me call it so - "Selection Rectangle" (see also my screenshot) that is shown when I Double-Click the item, right?  
2) To the ```super().mousePressEvent(sceneEvent)``` : I thouth that I am doing so, calling the scene's mouseEvent handler.... I put the method in the class MyScene(QGraphicsScene). Please, could you tell me how to implement this...? I simply don't know the syntax where to put this ```super().mousePressEvent(sceneEvent)``` ...
Anyway: Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: @musicamente: Forget about 2)... I guess You thought that the `def mousePressEvent(self, sceneEvent: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent):` was in a QGraphicsItem Subclass, and there I should use `super().mousePressEvent(sceneEvent)` to pass the event to the superior class, which is the scene. And in this case I would need  `super().mousePressEvent(sceneEvent)` in the reimplementation of the mousePressEvent in the Item's class. And there it would be just copy&paste. Thanks, this maybe useful 4 me in other places :-)

Comment: 1. Yes (and AFAIR and by reading the sources, as I'm not on a computer right now); but that "selection rectangle" is just to highlight the selected item, it doesn't actually reflect the shape used for its selection; 2. No, I was specifically pointing that aspect for the QGraphicsScene override: item selection is ***not*** directly managed by the items, but by the scene (that's a requirement, and it's the only way to manage extended selections): if you want to properly access item selection you *must* let the scene handle the mouse by calling `super().mousePressEvent()` from the scene.

Comment: @musicamente:
1: Cool thanks :-)'
2: OK.....but then I still don't know how to realize this in terms of syntax. So how and where in my example I call `super().mousePressEvent()`   ??? Thanks for answering :-)

Comment: @musicamante: I think I understood, where `super().mousePressEvent()` should be placed....see the updated code with #### Comments. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem...Or better I tried out something and I realized that my original problem is not a problem, but a feature lol

My original problem was that I cannot select the GraphicsItem I would like to select, because there are more than one Item at the scenePosition, or they are intersecting, which is the same when you look on a certain scenePostion.
It's like a stack of paper...if you want the 3rd piece of paper from the top, then you have to chose the 3rd paper of the top...using `itemAt(scenePosition, ...)` is like saying "Give me a paper from the paper stack on the table!"...so you get the topmost piece of paper.
Therefore I decided to take `items(scenePos)` of the QGraphicsScene and to loop through the list of the items at the scenePos and to pick the ones I need, and/or let the user decide.

But I added some Code to my original script. Now I can see the actual shape of a GraphicsItem. At least for the "standard"-ones, like a line, circle, polygon.
And what I saw is that the shapes are VERY precise:
[The black outline shows the shape of the drawn polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9a04.png)

And I also tried to implement an own method for the shape of a GraphicsItem.
But I am pretty sure that it's not that easy...
I use `my_GraphicsItem.shape = my_shape()`
Here's the Code:

```
# coding=utf-8

# File 4 stackoverflow question about the usage of PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.shape()

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent,
    QGraphicsItem,
    QTextEdit,
    QGraphicsLineItem,
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, QGraphicsEllipseItem, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsRectItem
    )
from PyQt5.QtGui import (
    QPolygonF, QPen, QTransform, QPainter,
    QPainterPath, QPixmap, QBrush, QColor, QFont, QIcon)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF, QLineF, QRectF
import sys

ppath = None

# Own QGraphicsScene Subclass with some drawings and points as example
class MyScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(-300, -300, 600, 600)
        self.ppath = None
        # Set QPen for drawings
        self.my_pen = QPen(Qt.darkRed)
        self.my_pen.setWidthF(15)
        self.my_pen.setCapStyle( Qt.RoundCap )

        # Set QBrush for drawings
        self.my_brush = QBrush( QColor( Qt.darkRed ),
                                Qt.BrushStyle( Qt.SolidPattern ) )


        
        # Draw a circle ( shape is created by my method.
        #               The created shape is senseless for a circle,
        #               and I guess, that this is NOT the right way to do it...)
        self.circle = self.addEllipse(
                QRectF( QPointF( -200, 100 ), QPointF( -100, 50 )),
                self.my_pen,
                self.my_brush
                )
        self.circle.setData(0, "Circle")
        self.circle.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.circle.shape = self.my_shape() # This ca
        
        
        # Set Start- & End-Points for my line
        self.start = QPointF(-250, -250)
        self.end = QPointF(-100, -100)
        
        # Draw a line (shape is created automatically)
        self.my_pen.setColor(Qt.green)
        self.my_pen.setWidth(25)
        
        self.lin = QGraphicsLineItem(QLineF(self.start, self.end))
        self.lin.setPen(self.my_pen)
        self.lin.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.lin.setData( 0, "Line" )
        self.addItem(self.lin)
        
        # Change Pen-Settings
        self.my_pen.setWidthF(5)
        self.my_pen.setColor(Qt.black)
        self.my_pen.setStyle(Qt.SolidLine)
        
        # Draw polygon
        self.my_brush.setColor(Qt.darkBlue)
        self.poly = self.addPolygon(
                QPolygonF(
                        [ QPointF( 10, -30 ),
                          QPointF( -30, 20 ),
                          QPointF( 180, 230 ),
                          QPointF( 230, 180 ),
                          QPointF( 270, 270 ),
                          QPointF( 240, 290 )
                          ] ),
                self.my_pen,
                self.my_brush
                )
        self.poly.setFlags( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.poly.setData( 0, "Polygon" )
    
    # Reimplementing the mousePressEvent for catching some information
    def mousePressEvent(self, sceneEvent: 'QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent'):
        if sceneEvent.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            text: str = ""
            # Get position and item at the position of the event
            pp = sceneEvent.scenePos()
            current_item = self.itemAt( pp, QTransform() )
            # So if there is an item at the clicked position, then write some information
            if current_item is not None:
                if current_item.data(0) != "Circle":
                    text = f"ItemData = {current_item.data( 0 )}\n" \
                           f"scenePos() = {pp} \n" \
                           f"screenPos() = {sceneEvent.screenPos()}\n" \
                           f"current_item.boundingRect() = " \
                           f"{current_item.boundingRect()}\n" \
                           f"current_item.shape() = {current_item.shape()}\n" \
                           f"current_item.shape().toFillPolygon() = " \
                           f"{current_item.shape().toFillPolygon()}\n"
                    self.my_pen.setColor(Qt.black)
                    self.my_pen.setWidth(2)
                    if self.ppath is not None:
                        self.removeItem(self.ppath)
                    self.ppath = self.addPolygon(current_item.shape().toFillPolygon(), self.my_pen)
           
                    # took this from here:
                    # https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QPainterPath.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QPainterPath.toFillPolygon
                else:
                    text = f"My Circle shape is not callable....however...\n" \
                        f"ItemData = {current_item.data( 0 )}\n" \
                           f"scenePos() = {pp} \n" \
                           f"screenPos() = {sceneEvent.screenPos()}\n" \
                           f"current_item.boundingRect() = " \
                           f"{current_item.boundingRect()}\n"
            else:
                text = f"scenePos = {pp}  But here is nothing"
            my_gui.my_textedit.setText( text )
        super().mousePressEvent( sceneEvent )
        # @ musicamente: As in this example I have only 2 Items which could be detected by
        # sceneEvent.scenePos() I call the super().mousePressEvent( sceneEvent ) at the end, so that I can move around
        # my items after all the stuff done above in the code.
        
    # This is surely NOT the right way...however
    def my_shape( self):
        my_painter_path = QPainterPath()
        my_painter_path.addPolygon(QPolygonF( [
                                QPointF( 20, -30 ),
                                QPointF( -30, 20 ),
                                QPointF( 180, 230 ),
                                QPointF( 230, 180 ),
                                ] ))
        return my_painter_path
    #

        
# The Class/Widget for placing the view for placing
class MyGui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 800)
        self.my_scene = MyScene()
        self.my_view = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.my_view.setScene(self.my_scene)
        
        # QTextEdit for displaying some stuff for debugging
        self.my_textedit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.my_textedit.setGeometry(0, 610, 600, 150)



# Starting the App
my_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
my_gui = MyGui()
my_gui.show()

sys.exit(my_app.exec())
```

I hope this might be helpful to somebody, except of me ;-)